# Redirect to http from https for a few pages htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I've following code in my htaceess:

```
RewriteRule ^productdetails/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+) /singlepro.php?cat=$1&sub=$2&fur=$3&name=$4&data=$5/
```

What happens is, if a person is already on https page, the above code redirects to https version. If I write the following code:

```
RewriteRule ^productdetails/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+) http://www.example.com/singlepro.php?cat=$1&sub=$2&fur=$3&name=$4&data=$5/
```

It shows URL as `http://www.example.com/singlepro.php?cat=aaa&sub=aaa&fur=aaa&name=aaa&data=aaa/`. I want to redirect to http plus it should show URL as /productdetails/../../..
Any idea what can be done?

**htaccess file**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^xyz\.php$ https://www.example.com/xyz.php [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^productdetails/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)
            /singlepro.php?cat=$1&sub=$2&fur=$3&name=$4&data=$5/
```

For some of the pages like xyz.php, I redirect them to https.

Comment: First rule doesn't redirect. Show your full .htaccess and tell what URL are you entering in browser?

Comment: First rule doesn't redirect, it shows content of the latter part. URL I'm entering in browser is the first portion, it's something like `a href='/productdetails/../../..'`

Comment: That comment is of no use. Unless until you provide full information nobody can help you.

Comment: Okay added htaccess file, have a look

Comment: What exact URL are you entering in browser and what does it get redirected to? You can mask you domain by using `example.com`

Answer (score 0):

If i understand well. Add on top of your `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^productdetails/ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```